# getDay() code showing wrong day Javascript

Tags: javascript, datetime, getdate

This is my first time (yep JS newbie) using `new Date()` and `getDay()` functions in Javascript. The current date given is correct, yet it gives me the day as Friday even thought it shows the day as Thursday if I get current date. I did do a check of previous questions on here but couldn't see any that really explained it. It gives the same result in both Chrome and Firefox. I also checked that my computer is set to the correct time zone, UK GMT.

Code:

```js
var currentDate = new Date();

console.log(currentDate);

var weekday = ['Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];

var day = weekday[currentDate.getDay()];

console.log(day);
```

***Time and day show in Console:***

> "Thu May 11 2017 22:25:15 GMT+0100 (BST) Fri"

[image: console screenshot]

Comment: Zero index --> Sunday
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay

Comment: Sunday is the first day of the week.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your array to `['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat']`.

(Sunday is the first day in the week if Javascript has a say in it ;)

```js
var currentDate = new Date();

var weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

var day = weekday[currentDate.getDay()];

console.log(day);
```

Comment: Aha! Now I know! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript Sunday = 0, Monday = 1....Saturday = 6. Change you weekday array as follows

```
var weekday = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tues', 'Wed', 'Thur', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
```